# While using selenium only getting the data;. page

Tags: python, selenium

**im trying to open at least google website but no matter what website i input still only get data;. page**

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH    =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Users/83735228/Desktop/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe')
driver  =   webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

**im trying to open at least google website but no matter what website i input still only get data;. page**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no you are doing it wrong, do this instead  :

```
from selenium import webdriver
PATH = r'C:/Users/83735228/Desktop/chromedriver_win32 (1)/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```